# three closed curves on torus

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$ be three closed curves in a torus with the following details:

- $C_1$ is a simple close curve (that is $C_1$ has no self intersection).
- $C_1$ meets $C_2$ at a single transverse crossing point. similarly, $C_1$ meets $C_3$ at a single transverse crossing point.
- $C_2$ intersects itself at three transverse crossing points. Similarly,  $C_3$ intersects itself at three transverse crossing points.
- $C_2$ and $C_3$ intersect transversely at three crossing points.

Can we find such curves in a torus or it's impossible? I think it's impossible. Because each of $C_2$ and $C_3$ intersects $C_1$ at a single transverse crossing  points which implies that $C_2$ is homologous to $C_3$ (I have doubt about this statement since neither $C_2$ nor $C_3$ is a simple closed curve). So can I conclude that they are homologous?). Now $C_2$ and $C_3$ meet transversely three times so they are not homologous. This is a contradiction. Any comment about the argument above is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible. See the figure below. I think you can imagine the self-intersections of $C_2$ and $C_3$. Just insert three little loops in both curves respectively.

[image]

Comment: I was just going to say precisely that self intersections make no difference, right?. Nice picture!

Comment: @Sak Thanks :) Right, they make no difference because they can be inserted locally as much as one needs.

Comment: @M.Winter cool picture. What method did you use to create it?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip You mean what software I used for the graphics (it's Mathematica) or you mean the formulas of the curves?

Comment: @M.Winter: I thought maybe you drew it freehand with adobe illustrator, but that makes sense that you used Mathematica. Nice job.